# Sqlite optimizing query using case when

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have three tables `A`,`B` and `C`. I have to detect if any of them have zero rows. As soon as any table with zero row is detected, I do not need to check other ones.

So, one way is I execute three queries separately and after each query I check the number of returned rows. If its non-zero then only I execute the query of next table.

Second way is I write a single query using `case-when`, something like

```
select case 
when (select count(*) from A = 0)
then 1
else (
      select case 
      when (select count(*) from B = 0)
      then 1 
      else (
           select case
           when (select count(*) from B = 0)
           then 1
           else 0
           )
      )
end as matchResult;
```

The second method requires lesser code as I have to write a single query and db will do the comparison for me.

My question is whether its overkilling or can I further optimize the query?

**EDIT**

On further study, I realise that the query above is wrong. However, I can simply do it as

```
select case 
when (select count(*) from A) = 0 and
     (select count(*) from B) = 0 and
     (select count(*) from C) = 0  
then 1
else 0
end as matchResult;
```

and if I am not wrong, `and` conditions are checked from left to right and if any one is false, conditions to the right are not checked.

Please confirm this point.

Comment: do you have some issues here yet?

Answer (score 1):

Count is kind of expensive

```
select 1  
where not exits (select * from a) 
   or not exits (select * from b) 
   or not exits (select * from c)
```

Answer (score -2):

One query with three resutls:

```
select (select count(*) from A) as Acount, 
       (select count(*) from B) as Bcount, 
       (select count(*) from C) as Ccount
```

This instead gives name of the fitst table that is empty:

```
select case
   when (select count(*) from A)=0 then 'A' 
   when (select count(*) from B)=0 then 'B'
   when (select count(*) from C)=0 then 'C'
   else 'ops, all have records'             -- remove this to have a null
end as first_empty_table
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @fancyPants, I am sure this is not "the answer", I just intend to give some tools to OP, as question is not totally clear, at least for me.

Comment: "I have to detect if any of them have zero rows" is not clear to you?

Comment: @Blam  What is not clear to me is that the sequence (witch table) fails seems important.  in other case it is just an **and**